# How to read a xml string into XMLTextReader type

Tags: c#, xml, string, xmltextreader

I have an XML string. I need to convert this string into **XMLTextReader**(System.Xml.XMLTextReader) type in dotnet.

I used the following code:

```
string szInputXml = "<TestDataXml><DataName>testing</DataName></TestDataXml>" ;
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(szInputXml));
```

But the string inside the **reader** is empty after execution.

Please help me to figure out what needs to be done to get the XMLTextReader to be populated with the given string.

Comment: Do not use `new XmlTextReader()`. It has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Comment: Also, you must have something else going on. A `new` expression cannot return null.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, why is it deprecated?

Comment: Many reasons. Lack of flexibility and features,mainly

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How do you determine if the string is empty?

```
string szInputXml = "<TestDataXml><DataName>testing</DataName></TestDataXml>";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader( new System.IO.StringReader( szInputXml ) );
reader.Read();
string inner = reader.ReadInnerXml();
```

Without 3rd line "inner" was empty indeed. Now it contains testing.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is like an IDataReader.Read() in the sense that when you do a .Read, it goes to the next element.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx